# Reuse JSON patches in kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, json-patch, kustomize

I am using a JSON patch in my overlay kustomization file in order to set the image to use for my pods.

The patch itself is pretty generic:

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/image
  value: myRegistry/myImage:myTag
```

And in my `kustomization.yml`:

```
patchesJson6902:
  - target:
      group: apps
      version: v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: myDeployment
    path: patch_image.yml
```

By using this method, I have to use a different patch for each deployment that uses a different image. Is there a way to move the patch `value` field up to the `kustomization.yml` file, where I could do something like:

```
patchesJson6902:
  - target:
      group: apps
      version: v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: myDeploymentA
    path: patch_image.yml
    value: myRegistry/myImageA:myTag
  - target:
      group: apps
      version: v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: myDeploymentB
    path: patch_image.yml
    value: myRegistry/myImageB:myTag
```

Comment: I just found that y exact example can be solved with https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples/transformerconfigs#images-transformer but the problem of patch reuse is still not solved.

Comment: You seem to want parameterized patches, and that is not possible with kustomize. You could write the whole patch inline but the `op` and `path` would have to be part of it.